# Getting error while adding watcher to JIRA ticket using JIRA python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm trying to add watchers after creating the issue using python but while adding into after creating issue getting below error, Can anyone help?

```
TypeError: unbound method add_watcher() must be called with JIRA instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)
```

Code:

```
def aus_issue(self):
    self.issue_aus = {
        'project': {'key': 'MOS'},
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Reporting'},
        'summary': 'Test NDP Data Audit {} AUS'.format(Jira.date_create().strftime('%B')),
        'description': self.description,
        'customfield_10038': {'value': 'AUS'},
        'customfield_10052': {'value': 'Ad hoc'},
        'customfield_10053': {'value': 'Monthly'},
        "assignee": {
            "name": ""
        }, 'duedate': str(Jira.sixth_day())}

    self.create_aus = self.client.create_issue(fields=self.issue_aus, prefetch=True)
    JIRA.add_watcher(self.create_aus.id, watcher='UserName')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the instance of JIRA class is: "self.client"

For add_watcher, you need to use it as:
self.client.add_watcher(self.create_aus.id, watcher='UserName')